# Как правильно: это знание умирает (одно/одиним) из первых.

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно: "*это знание умирает одно из первых*" или"*это знание умирает одним из первых*"? И почему?

Answer (score 3):

Это знание умирает (возникает, является) *каким по счёту*? Одн**им** из первых. 
*Чем* оно является? Одн**им** из первых знаний. /тв. падеж/

ср. Это знание (есть, было) какое по счёту? - одн**о** из первых (появившихся) знаний. /им. падеж/

Comment: Полностью фраза звучит так: когда происходит обесценивание всех знаний, знание орфографии отмирает одно из первых.